# Rewriting an url for a user-defined domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible and tried searching but couldn't find the exact answer to my current situation.

I'm building a service which should allow users to point their own domain to the service. (they need to point an A record towards my server ip)

I'm able to catch the domain using the catch all in apache. So I made a Vhost record for this catch all in httpd.conf. So all not-defined hostnames in apache are pointed towards a certain directory.

Now I would like to pass this domain as a parameter to my service. So is it possible to point this.randomdomain.com to www.mywebserviceurl.com/domain/catch/this.randomdomain.com with .htaccess

The address bar should keep the url this.randomdomain.com

**Edit:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blogs/string/$1 [R=301]
```

The above is redirecting but firefox trows an error "The page isn't redirecting properly - Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." 
And the address is changing which I don't want.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude that domain from the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blogs/string/$1 [R=301]
```

And if you want the domain too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blogs/string/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: thanks, this is working, but how can I make this invisible for the user?

Comment: You will probably use a proxy (requires mod_proxy) to do that. Just add the `P` flag.

Comment: if I change [R=301] to [P] it breaks the redirect and I'll get a 404 page not found.

Comment: I probably don't have mod_proxy enabled, will check that.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

The directive %{HTTP_REFERER} should do what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gumbo's answer, but change the arguments in the braces, you can silently redirect. Change `[R=301]` to `[L]`, which means it's the last rule that will be executed.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blogs/string/$1 [L,P]
```

Edit: After seeing Gumbo's answer, you'll also need mod_proxy enabled and add the P flag.

Comment: I've changed it to [L] the redirect keeps working but he isn't doing it silently. It changes the address bar.

Comment: Gumbo's updated answer should work. I've edited my response to match his.